# Pandas pivot_table using a given list of indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like some help to figure out how to pivot a pandas dataframe into a table with a given list of indices and columns (instead of the default behavior where the indices and columns are picked automatically by pandas). Apologies if this is trivial. I am new to python/pandas.

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import datetime
data = {
'ticker' : np.array(['AAPL', 
               'AAPL',
               'IBM', 
               'XOM']), 
              'trade_date' : np.array([datetime.datetime(2015,01,01), 
                                    datetime.datetime(2015,04,02),
                                    datetime.datetime(2099,01,01), 
                                    datetime.datetime(2015,03,01)]), 
             'price' : np.array([10.0, 15.6, 20.9, 13.5])
  }
x = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

Upon pivot_table,

```
x.pivot_table(values = "price", index = "trade_date", columns = "ticker")
```

the result is:

```
ticker      AAPL   IBM   XOM
trade_date                  
2015-01-01  10.0   NaN   NaN
2015-03-01   NaN   NaN  13.5
2015-04-02  15.6   NaN   NaN
2099-01-01   NaN  20.9   NaN
```

However, what I want is:

```
ticker      A    AA  AAPL   IBM   XOM
trade_date                  
2015-01-01  NaN  NaN 10.0   NaN   NaN
2015-01-02  NaN  NaN NaN    NaN   NaN
2015-03-01  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN  13.5
2015-04-02  NaN  NaN 15.6   NaN   NaN
2099-01-01  NaN  NaN NaN  20.9   NaN
```

There does not seem to be any provisions in pivot_table() to force a set of indices and columns.

Is there a fast way of doing this? The data sets are fairly large, and it would help to do this fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd reindex *after* pivoting:

```
In [11]: df = x.pivot_table(values = "price", index = "trade_date", columns = "ticker")

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
ticker      AAPL   IBM   XOM
trade_date
2015-01-01  10.0   NaN   NaN
2015-03-01   NaN   NaN  13.5
2015-04-02  15.6   NaN   NaN
2099-01-01   NaN  20.9   NaN

In [13]: df.reindex_axis(["A", "AA", "AAPL", "IBM", "XOM"], axis=1)
Out[13]:
ticker       A  AA  AAPL   IBM   XOM
trade_date
2015-01-01 NaN NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN
2015-03-01 NaN NaN   NaN   NaN  13.5
2015-04-02 NaN NaN  15.6   NaN   NaN
2099-01-01 NaN NaN   NaN  20.9   NaN
```